# How to cherry pick old repo changes into new repo with different layout

Tags: git

Our infrastructure team has decided to combine a bunch of git repos into a new single repo with a directory for each of the old repos. Of course, we all have dev branches we're working on that are not ready to commit.

Anyone know of a good way to move a branch over to the new repo with a "relative directory adjustment"?

For example -

Old repos:

```
ProjectA
   file1
   file2

ProjectB
   filex
   filey
```

New repo:

```
ShinyNewRepo
   ProjectA
      file1
      file2
   ProjectB
      filex
      filey
```

Say I have a feature branch in old `ProjectA` that's not ready to merge. Is there a slick way to get that feature branch into `ShinyNewRepo` such that it understands all the files have moved under a new subdirectory called `ProjectA`?

One possible way I can think of would be to simply export the feature branch changes to regular old patch files, and then import them back into the new repo with appropriate relative location changes so they end up patching the same files in their new locations. This won't capture any history, but that's not that important.

Comment: Do you mean your project A will continue to evolve in its own branch from current repo and want an othor projectA in the newrepo ?

Comment: The structures above represent directory trees only. there are no branches or tags represented, but I may have a change to file1 in old ProjectA on a feature branch. I'd like to transplant that feature branch to ShinyNewRepo with some meta-data indicating that the file changes have moved down a level.